# The Multi-part identifier could not bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read the other posts on this issue and I haven't really found one that receives this error from the situation I have.

For the following query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EightIDs (Email)
    SELECT Email
    FROM dbo.TempTransferTable
    WHERE dbo.TempTransferTable.EightID = dbo.EightIDs.EID
```

I receive an error

> Multi-part identifier could not be bound

on the `dbo.EightIDs.EID` part of the query. I'm not sure why it's giving me a problem when I'm basically just trying to match the IDs in one table with the IDs in a second table, then bring over the Emails accordingly.

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments about using `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`, here's what I came up with. Does this seem more appropriate?

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET tbl1.Email = tbl2.Email
FROM dbo.EightIDs tbl1
JOIN dbo.TempTransferTable tbl2 ON tbl2.EightID = tbl1.EID
```

Comment: You want to update existing records right? Then use `update` and not `insert`

Comment: Sounds like you need an update join

Comment: So I have two tables - EightIDs and TempTransferTable, both of which have an EightID / EID (matching values) and an Email field. Currently, the Email fields in EightIDs table are all empty (null), so I'd like to migrate the emails from TempTransferTable to EightIDs. Would update or insert into be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mentioned the table name or alias name in front of the column name. Hope the Email column is exists in the both tables:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.EightIDs (Email)
SELECT TT.Email
FROM dbo.TempTransferTable TT
JOIN dbo.EightIDs EI ON EI.EID = TT.EightID
```

Or if you want to UPDATE the column to EightIDs based on TempTransferTable, you can use the below query:

```
UPDATE EI
SET EI.Email = TT.Email
FROM dbo.EightIDs EI
JOIN dbo.TempTransferTable TT ON TT.EightID = EI.EID
```

Comment: So I have two tables - EightIDs and TempTransferTable, both of which have an EightID / EID (matching values) and an Email field. Currently, the Email fields in EightIDs table are all empty (null), so I'd like to migrate the emails from TempTransferTable to EightIDs. Would update or insert into be more appropriate?

Comment: If you have an EightID / EID (matching values), then you need to update. Insert will create duplicate records